# concatenacion de una vista , json en laravel full calendar

Tags: laravel, json

¿Es posible concatenar una vista y un json para poder mostrar todo a la vez?

```
 public function index(){  

    view('admin.calendario')
    $data = Event::get(['id','title','placa','start']);

    return Response()->json($data);
}
```

tengo la vista y el json  y necesito retornar los dos  al mismo tiempo para poder visualizar la informacion en un calendario pero no he podido

---

la libreria que utilizo es full calendar la cuestion es que me guarda los datos que ingreso pero nos los puedo visualizar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces se me ocurrio concatenar el json a  la visto para poder visualizar todos los datos que se han guardado y en su pocision ingresada 
la idea es que se visualize de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el json que estoy recolectando es:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = Event::get(['id','title','placa','start']);

    return Response()->json($data);
}
```

pero no he podido  lograrlo si retorno uuno no puedo lo otro

Comment: ¿Qué paquete estás utilizando o qué pretendes hacer con los dos datos? Tal vez puedas mostrarnos los datos de la vista y del json para entender un poco mejor

Comment: Estas usando Laravel?

Comment: si estoy utilizando laravel 5.5

Comment: Cual es la razón de concatenar el json con la vista del calendario. ¿Mostrar los eventos en el calendario?. Al generar tu calendario puedes utilizar el método `addEvents` que seria la lista de eventos que obtienes con el `Event::get` solo que te falta los datos de los campos `all_day, end` `$calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($events)`

Comment: comparto el enlace donde respondo mi pregunta y donde lo estoy realizando de una manera mas sencilla claro en mi concepto y me funciona muy bien https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/144466/77077