# Cargar registros de Base de Datos a partir de un Select con Ajax, Laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Estoy realizando un pequeño formulario dónde solicito que seleccionen el nombre de un usuario por medio de un Select:

```
<select class="form-control dynamic" id="tipopersona" name="tipopersona" data-dependent="empresa">
   <option value="" selected="true" disabled="true">Seleccione Tipo de Persona</option>
    @foreach($tpersona as $tp => $value)
   <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{$value->t_persona}}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
```

La idea es que al seleccionar a un usuario pueda obtener todos los datos guardados de ese usuario en la base de datos y luego mostrarlos en diferentes input de mi vista.

Comment: que version de laravel usas ?

Comment: esto te servira https://tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-ajax-tutorial

Comment: Hola, disculpa la demora, utilizo laravel 5.5

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo seguir este artículo que ya he realizado con el mismo objetivo. Si te ayuda, valora positiva la respuesta, de otra forma, comunícame y con gusto realizo la solución para tu caso concreto, aunque con el siguiente enlace debería ser suficiente. Saludos!
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/140808/laravel-fullcalendar-cargas-datos-de-manera-din%C3%A1mica/141500#141500